# Convert Json Rest to Java DTO

Tags: java, json, rest

is there a way that I can take the DTO's from a REST api? I want to create my DTO's automaticaly from the JSON REST api. Is there some way?

Comment: From JSON to DTO conversion right? Possible. Could u plz do some googling before ask any question in SO?

Comment: I did, I found this but is not usefull at all:

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

http://timboudreau.com/blog/json/read

Comment: Which JAX-RS reference implementation r u using?

Comment: I am using Retrofit for android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some years, this is what I wanted:

https://app.quicktype.io/

Answer (score 1):

You can try use a framework library like [RESTEasy (Jboss Suite)](http://resteasy.jboss.org/) or [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) or [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Then you only need define a estructure same a you class for example, if your class is something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"entityName\"")
public class Entity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3469107762875646075L;

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    public Entity() {
    }

    //getters and setters
```

---

The interface will receive an object of that type.

```
@POST
@Path("/create")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
Response createEntity(Entity entityObject);
```

---

And JSON be this way, then the conversion is automatic.

```
{
"id":"99",
"name":"stackoverflow"
}
```

**NOTE: The information received must be of the same type defined in your Class to perform this conversion.**

Comment: But I want Java DTO from Json Object, you are telling me the contrary. I have Json from an API and I need to do every DTO class to get the response.

Comment: Look carefully at the "create Entity" method, which receives as a parameter an object of type "Entity" and when you make a POST http request type in the payload will be sent to the JSON object, and will receive transformed.

Comment: I think you are not understanding me. I need to transform JSON response to DTO POJO class but I dont know how to do it.

I going to explain myself... I do a request to an external API, then it give me a response but I do not have any DTO class to save the information that it is sending me. So I want to know how to create thats DTO's automatically to use in my application.

Thank you very much, you are trying to help me :), if you dont understand something, just tell me, I am not english speaker native.

Comment: Now I understand what you mean, you could try to use the library [Jackson](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson) to do this, look at the next [article](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)

Comment: I have looked Jackson library, but is the same, it do not create the POJOS from JSON, I think I must to do it for myself :/

Thank you anyway :)